# Odoo10 api constrains stuck

Tags: python, odoo

My constrains method not working for id_number. can't figure it out why.

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class KindeGarden(models.Model):
    _inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}
    _name = 'kindergarten.model'
    _description = 'Kindergarten'

   age = fields.Integer(string="Amžius", required=False, default="1")
   group = fields.Char(string="Grupė", compute="_compute_group", store=True)
   height = fields.Float(string="Ūgis", required=False)
   weight = fields.Float(string="Svoris",  required=False)
   id_number = fields.Integer(string="Registravimo Nr", required=True)

   @api.constrains('id_number')
   def _check_id_number_field(self):
       for i in self:
           if i.id_number < 10:
               raise ValidationError("Number is to small")
```

and i'm also having this

WARNING -Kindegarden odoo.models.schema: Table 'kindergarten_model': unable to set a NOT NULL constraint on column 'id_number' !
If you want to have it, you should update the records and execute manually:
ALTER TABLE kindergarten_model ALTER COLUMN id_number SET NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned above, it looks like it is some data are null already before you set required parameter to true.

odoo has a shell you can use to access your DB if you are not familiar with SQL.

```
odoo-bin -d <database_name> shell
```

inside the shell, do as follow so you will see.

```
>> records = env['kindergarten.model'].search([('id_number','=',False)])
>> len(records)
```

if it returns a number aside from 0, it means that those are NULL value. so do like.

```
>> for record in records:
       record.write({'id_number': 0.0})
>>env.cr.commit()
```

Then update your module again.

If this doesn't work you will need to do it manually with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add constraint after few records were added ?

The error you got generally comes when  postgres is unable to set "NOT NULL" to the column because it already has null values

Comment: probably but i can't really tell for sure. so is there solution for this? because method is not working for sure

Comment: if you have access to db then try seeing if any records with id_number as NULL exists or not .. or if you can delete the records after your module was installed then also it might help. But if this is not on test server and production data is involved then scenario is bit risky